# How to efficiently apply function to rows of large pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to create a training dataset for a model from a current data set. Its for blackjack and each row is how a player plays their hands.

The table might look something like this:

```
|Card1|Card2|Card3|Card4|Card5|PlayerTotal|DealerCard1|Win/Lose
|   7 | 10  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  17       |    10     |  0
|   4 | 3   |  10 |  0  |  0  |  17       |     8     |  1
```

Id like to turn it into rows with just the sum of the players hand, the dealers card and the win/lose. However, if more than 2 cards have been played (so the player hit) then id like to make multiple rows for that sample with the game at each stage (so before the player hits each time)

So the example would become:

```
|PlayerTotal|DealerCard1|Win/Lose
|    17     |     10    |  0
|    7      |     8     |  1
|    17     |     8     |  1
```

How can I do this efficiently?

I can do this fine with a small dataset using pd.apply and a custom function with if statements, but once I use the whole dataset (~1 mill points) its very slow and memory intensive.

Something like this:

```py
def extractRounds(x):
    totals = []
    totals.append(x[0:2], x[5], x[6]])

    if x[2] > 0:
        totals.append([sum(x[0:3]), x[5], x[6]])
    else:
        return pd.Series(totals)

    if x[3] > 0:
        totals.append([sum(x[0:4]), x[5], x[6]])
    else:
        return pd.Series(totals)

    if x[4] > 0:
        totals.append([sum(x[0:5]), x[5], x[6]])

    return pd.Series(totals)


b = (a.apply(extractRounds, axis = 1)).stack()
```

Im guessing that it is the `extractRounds(x)` function that isn't the most effective or efficient.

So im wondering if I am barking up the wrong tree trying to do this by applying a function to each row or if there is a better way?

Let me know if this isn't clear. Cheers!

Comment: In the second line of your output, if DealerCard1 was '6', then you would want to have '0' in the last column?

Comment: No because the win/lose column is whether hand was won in the end. Not whether the current hand will win or lose. This comes from the dataset which is a whole heap of blackjack hands played and their results. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, so you can do some symbol manipulation first to add the extra lines and then do the summation. Is your data in CSV format?

Comment: Yep it is but I have been reading it in through pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use melt to convert your data into long format, add a cumulative sum, and then just exclude the zero card values for cards 3-5. And exclude card 1 since the player will always have a minimum of 2 cards.

Here's your example as a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw = pd.DataFrame({'Card1': [7, 4],
                    'Card2': [10, 3],
                    'Card3': [0, 10],
                    'Card4': [0, 0],
                    'Card5': [0, 0],
                    'DealerCard1': [10, 8],
                    'PlayerTotal': [17, 17],
                    'Win/Lose': [0, 1]})

raw.index.name = 'Game'
```

Use melt to create another dataframe in long format:

```
df = (raw.reset_index()
     .melt(value_vars=['Card1', 'Card2', 'Card3', 'Card4', 'Card5'], 
           id_vars=['Game', 'DealerCard1', 'Win/Lose'],
           value_name='CardValue', 
           var_name='Card')
     .sort_values('Game')
     .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Recreate the PlayerTotal column as a cumulative sum:

```
df['PlayerTotal'] = df.groupby('Game')['CardValue'].apply(np.cumsum)
```

And then you can just exclude card 1 and the zero cards and select your desired columns:

```
df.loc[(df['CardValue']!=0) & (df['Card']!='Card1'), ['PlayerTotal', 'DealerCard1', 'Win/Lose']]
```

That will give you:

```
PlayerTotal DealerCard1 Win/Lose
1   17  10  0
6   7   8   1
7   17  8   1
```

Comment: Thank you. This is much better! Still takes a little while to run on the whole dataset but otherwise much quicker than what I was doing before :) The only thing I changed to work on all of the samples was to add 'Card' to the sort so it got the order correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use command-line tools to add the extra lines to the csv file and do the summation.

Let's say first few lines of CSV file `data.csv` is

```
Card1,Card2,Card3,Card4,Card5,PlayerTotal,DealerCard1,Win/Lose
7,10,0,0,0,17,10,0
4,3,10,0,0,17,8,1
```

Running the following command gives us the desired output

```sh
sed 's/\(.*,\)\(.*,\)\([1-9][0-9]*,\)\(.*,.*,.*,.*,.*\)/\1\2\3\4\n\1\20,\4/' data.csv | cut -d ',' -f 1,2,3,7,8 | awk -F ',' 'NR>1 {print $1+$2+$3 "," $4 "," $5}' > data_2.csv
```

It creates a file named `data_2.csv` containing

```
17,10,0
17,8,1
7,8,1
```

### --------------------------------

**Explanation of the command:**

```
sed 's/\(.*,\)\(.*,\)\([1-9][0-9]*,\)\(.*,.*,.*,.*,.*\)/\1\2\3\4\n\1\20,\4/' data.csv
```

reads the `data.csv` line by line, if a line has 0 value in third column, it adds another line where the third column is 0.

```
| cut -d ',' -f 1,2,3,7,8
```

reads the data from previous step and filter the data to columns 1,2,3,7,8 (these are the columns we care about)

```
| awk -F ',' 'NR>1 {print $1+$2+$3 "," $4 "," $5}' > data_2.csv
```

reads the data from previous step, adds up the first three columns and writes it in a file called `data_2.csv` together with the last two columns.